# Upgrading PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.3 on EC2

Tags: yum, fedora, php5, rpm, upgrade

I am a HUGE novice with this, and I have spend a whole day and a night trying to fix this. I know this has been asked before, but I have tried everything in those answers as well as from all over the Internet, nothing works :-(

So I thought I will seek help here.

My problem is:

- I have a Linux box that is an `EC2 machine`
- When I do a `cat /etc/redhat-release` it says `Fedora release 8 (Werewolf)`
- When I do a `php -v` it says `PHP 5.2.6`
- I need to upgrade from `PHP 5.2.6 to >= PHP 5.3`

What I have tried so far:

I read some articles and deleted the current PHP using:

```
yum remove php
yum remove php-common
yum remove php-cli
```

All of these commands worked successfully, but when I did a `yum info php` it still said `PHP 5.2.6` is installed!

Undaunted by this, I downloaded the `PHP 5.3 rpms` from `http://rpms.famillecollet.com/archives/fedora/8/remi/i386/repoview/` using

```
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/archives/fedora/8/remi/i386/php-5.3.8-1.fc8.remi.i386.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/archives/fedora/8/remi/i386/php-cli-5.3.8-1.fc8.remi.i386.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/archives/fedora/8/remi/i386/php-common-5.3.8-1.fc8.remi.i386.rpm
```

Each of these rpm install commands worked successfully. Then I did

`yum upgrade php` and the system said:

```
...
Setting up Upgrade Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

Next, I tried `yum install php` and the system said:

```
...
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
Package matching php-5.2.6-2.fc8.i386 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do
```

`php -v` still says `5.2.6`. How can I upgrade to `php 5.3`?

Any pointers are very much appreciated!

Comment: Fedora 8? That is so far out of date that you should not even be attempting to use it. Start over with a current operating system distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Hampton's comment is very relevant - Fedora 8 is ancient. It would be a very good idea to get yourself on something a little more modern!

All that being said, it's entirely possible that both 5.2 and 5.3 are installed, but that 5.2 appears first in the path. If that's the case, it'll run 5.2 because it's the first one that it finds.

You can find all the instances with:

```
find / -name php 2> /dev/null
```

(the "2> /dev/null" bit is to keep the screen clear of the clutter that comes of pointing `find` at the root filesystem)

Armed with the list, you can explicitly call each one and see if you're got 5.3 lurking somewhere.